# Uncaught Error: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.0.102 (port 19000) from / 192.168.0.100 (port 42950) after 10000ms

Tags: react-native

My react native project run on android emulator
but whenever i try to connect my project with my android device then above error occur.

**note: my mobile and laptop are connected with the same wifi connection.**
Please help me with this issue.

**Uncaught Error: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.0.102 (port 19000) from / 192.168.0.100 (port 42950) after 10000ms**

Answer (score 1):

> - While running expo I got this error.
> - Turn on USB Tethering & USB Debugging Mode in your mobile.
>   [image: enabled tethering]
>   [image]
> - Connect your mobile to your laptop through USB.
> - Running app in expo app.
>   [image]
> - close the terminal and reopen.
> - if didn't work let me know.
>   [for more info click me](https://github.com/expo/create-react-native-app/issues/876)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Expo Go, You can this problem in 2 ways.

**First way.**

Remove Expo Go cache and try to restart the app.

**Second way**

If you are using wifi turn off wifi and try to connect your desktop and mobile with mobile hotspot

Comment: thanks for reply. I tried both way but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

i have also gone through similar issue. But after trying out possible solution for two days i was able to use a solution that works for me. I just went to my android phone and access the expo app info then i went to the storage the clear the cash and also clear the data. From there i went back run the project app again and was able to run the app in my phone again.

Answer (score -2):

Please go through your Wifi Properties from your laptop and change the settings from Public to Private. It worked for me!!!

Comment: https://github.com/expo/create-react-native-app/issues/876